# ¿Cómo redimensionar múltiples imágenes , es posible con una sola función?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hay una forma de no repetir el método (resize) que sirve para redimensionar la imagen. Cabe resaltar que son muchas, muchas imágenes y no es dable repetir un método tantas veces creo yo.

```py
class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.img_1=Label(self,image=self.image_1)
        self.img_1.bind('<Configure>',self.resize)
        self.img_1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        
        self.img_2=Label(self,image= self.image_2)  
        self.img_2.bind('<Configure>',self.resize)       
        self.img_2.pack(fill=BOTH, expand =YES)

        self.img_3=Label(self,image= self.imagen_3) 
        self.img_3.bind('<Configure>',self.resize)
        self.img_3.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

    def resize(self,event):

        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height

        var1= self.img_1_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))
        var2= ImageTk.PhotoImage(var1)

        self.img_1.config(image= var2)
        self.img_1.image=var2
```

Comment: 1. modifica la fuente del texto 2. un ciclo `for` te serviría

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siempre que tengas código de estructura repetitiva, es un síntoma de que debes cambiar el código a un bucle, y las variables a una lista.

En tu caso, cada imagen es un atributo separado del objeto (`self.img_1`, `self.img_2`, `self.img_3`, etc.) lo que hace casi imposible iterar por ellas en un bucle. En lugar de eso deberías tener un solo atributo, llamémosle `self.imgs` que sea una lista, y cuyos elementos sean cada una de las imágenes.

Lo mismo debes hacer con tus atributos `self.image_1`, `self.image_2`, etc (que no se ve dónde se inicializan) y cambiarlas por otra lista, digamos `self.imgs`. Parece que también tienes otra serie de imágenes llamadas `self.img1_copy`, etc. y no está claro en este caso si son imágenes o labels (supongo que imágenes) ya que tampoco se muestra en tu código cómo se inicializan.

Eso te permitirá también iterar por ellas en la función `__init__()` evitando también el código repetitivo de esa función.

Usando este enfoque, el código que suministras en la pregunta quedaría así:

```py
class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # se supone que en este punto el atributo self.images existe
        # y ya está inicializado con una lista de imágenes. Vamos a 
        # inicializar ahora la lista de imgs
        self.imgs = []

        for image in self.images:
           # Crear la imagen, reescalarla, etc.
           img = Label(self, image=image)
           img.bind('<Configure>',self.resize)
           img.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
           # Y añadir el resultado a la lista
           self.imgs.append(img)


    def resize(self,event):
        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height

        # En este punto se supone que existe una lista llamada 
        # self.imgs_copy, que no queda claro en qué punto debería
        # ser creada o inicializada, quizás en el propio __init__?
        for img_copy in self.imgs_copy:
           ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))
```

Como ves en el código quedan algunas lagunas por rellenar que no has mostrado en tu código en la pregunta como de dónde salen las imágenes en sí (que tú tenías en `self.image_1`, etc y ahora estarían en la lista `self.images`) o las copias de las mismas (que tú tenías en `self.img_1_copy` etc y ahora estarían en la lista `self.imgs_copy`)

Comment: Estas en lo correcto en todo lo que supones,   pero como harías para posicionar un objeto de la lista de label que creaste, ya que la imagen redimensionarlas no la posicionas , ni la reemplazas . Gracias por responder.